# How can I turn off pictures in powerpoint thumbnail icons?

Tags: icons, microsoft-powerpoint, desktop-icons

In windows 7 all of my powerpoint files show the title image in the icon.  Is there anyway to turn this off show it just shows some default powerpoint icon.  I find it hard to actually find my ppt presentations as the icons are all different.

Comment: I have the same issue and I am aware of the "always show icons, never thumbnails" option in windows 7. but I want this only turned on for MS office documents, but not for pictures, movies etc. Is there any possibility apply these settings for specific file types?

Answer (score 3):

- Click the "Organize" option from File Explorer (Upper left) in the folder/document repository.
- Select "Folder and Search Options".
- Click the "View" tab.
- Check "Always show icons, never thumbnails" box.